# Check if active window handle is password box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, passwords, pinvoke

i want to check if the active window handle is password box.

this function returns me the active control handle of the active window:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class FormMain
    Inherits Form

    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As IntPtr

    Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal ProcessId As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    Private Declare Function AttachThreadInput Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal idAttach As IntPtr, ByVal idAttachTo As IntPtr, ByVal fAttach As Boolean) As IntPtr

    Private Declare Function GetFocus Lib "user32.dll" () As IntPtr

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
        InitializeComponent
    End Sub

    Private Sub timerUpdate_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        labelHandle.Text = ("hWnd: " + FocusedControlInActiveWindow.ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Function FocusedControlInActiveWindow() As IntPtr
        Dim activeWindowHandle As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow
        Dim activeWindowThread As IntPtr = GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero)
        Dim thisWindowThread As IntPtr = GetWindowThreadProcessId(Me.Handle, IntPtr.Zero)
        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, true)
        Dim focusedControlHandle As IntPtr = GetFocus
        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, false)
        Return focusedControlHandle
    End Function
End Class
```

now i want to do something like:

```
if FocusedControlInActiveWindow() <> intptr.zero then
dim IsPass as boolean = isPassword(FocusedControlInActiveWindow())
if IsPass then
msgbox("yes")
else
msgbox ("no")
end if
end if
```

how can i check if the foucsed control in the active window text is `passwordcahr`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a Windows Edit Control has the [ES_PASSWORD style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464.aspx), this is how to do it:

```
Public Shared Function HasPasswordStyle(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
    Return ((GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) And ES_PASSWORD) <> 0)
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Const ES_PASSWORD As Integer = 32
Private Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = -16
```

Comment: Probably should be `GetWindowLongPtr` these days. I guess it doesn't matter for this use, but using `GetWindowLongPtr` saves you having to think about the 64 -> 32 bit truncation